# How to use VBA code without a macro trigger

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following VBA to run a macro when a value chosen from a dropdown changes, and the code works fine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D5")
            Case "2008": Macro1
            Case "2015": Macro1
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

However I would like to run the following event when another cell changes (also a drop down), the code is written to hide columns, this is the snippet of the additional code:

```
Sub hideColumnsBasedOnConditionZero()
LastColumn = 11 'Last Column
For i = 1 To LastColumn 'Lopping through each Column
    'Hide all the columns with the values as 0 in Row 11
    If Cells(1, i) = 0 And Cells(1, i) <> "" Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next
End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?  The second code is valid but I cannot activate it as the first code is using the change function and is specific to another cell.

Comment: for clarity, I want to leave the first code as it is, but get the Sub hideColumnsBasedOnConditionZero() to run when cell D4 changes

Comment: have the change function drive an if() to choose which of the two codes to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add it to your first event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case .Range("D5")
                Case "2008", "2015": Macro1
            End Select
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, .Range("Your Other Range")) Is Nothing Then
            Call hideColumnsBasedOnConditionZero
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```